# Check SMART status on MacOS and pop up alert

Tags: beginner, bash, status-monitoring, macos, applescript

So I don't know much about bash scripting.  I am just a beginner.  I made this script which checks the SMART status of my root volume and if it is failing then it immediately throws a pop up alert if my drive is failing.
Here's the code:

```
A=$( diskutil info disk0 | grep SMART )

if [ "$A" != "   SMART Status:             Verified" ]
then

osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to activate' -e 'tell 
application "Finder" to display dialog "Your Drive is failing, 
Please backup all your important files now" buttons 
{"OK"} with icon stop'
fi
```

I know this is so simple. Do you have any suggestions to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- A direct string comparison test may be flaky especially if the string contains multiple space characters. I can think of three alternatives:

  - Use regex matching: this can be achieved by the `=~` operator inside `[[ ]]`: `if [[ ! "$A" =~ Verified ]]`.
  - Use `awk`:

    ```
    A=$(diskutil info disk0 | awk '/SMART Status:/{print $NF}')
    if [ "$A" != 'Verified' ]
    # ...
    ```
  - Check exit status instead of output:

    ```
    if sudo smartctl -H -q silent /dev/disk0
    # ...
    ```
- Use more descriptive names: `smart_status_text` is more self-evident than `A`.
- Properly format your code: indent the commands inside the `if` block and don't leave a blank line after `then`.